# Cannot run gulp and karma on windows (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, karma-runner, mean-stack

I am making a MEAN course, and in one of the homeworks I have to work with gulp and karma for automated testing.

I am trying to run karma and gulp according to the instructions given in  [HMW 4.1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-UP5lxiQ9AodEotYjhIanlMUE0/view?usp=sharing) but I always have an error. Here are my steps:

1. Download and Extract the zip into a folder
2. Change to the directory HMW4 (where the homework is) and run `npm install`
3. Change the directory to `node_modules\gulp\bin` and run `gulp watch`
4. Windows open the JavaScript file instead of running. Why?

With Karma, I did something similar:

1. After trying to run gulp and failing, change to the directory `node_modules/karma/bin`
2. Run `karma start`
3. I get the following command like error `'karma' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

What am I missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: Try to install karma globally with command npm install karma -g

Comment: Isn't that a bad thing? Should I not be trying to avoid global installation of packages because of different projects ?

Comment: First try to add it globally and check whether you are getting same error or not. If not, then will check what will be best possible solution to this.

Comment: What type of error you get? Maybe you have problems with PATH variable?

Comment: I don't get an error, in the gulp case, it just opens teh JS file. In the karma case, says it does not recognize the command.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I installed Ubuntu LTS 14.04 in a VM using virtual box and indeed now everything seems to work perfectly. I would like to point out that running this code on Windows or in any other version of LInux is likely to bring problems, but in the specific Ubuntu version I previously mentioned, it works as intended.

I shall now close this question, hopefully it will help others.